Импорт модуля и if __name__ == "__main__"
Уже который раз натыкаюсь на проблемы с импортами в python. Давайте представим что у нас есть такая структура проекта:
app/

main.py
utils/

file1.py
file2.py



Здесь модуль file1 импортирует модуль file2, а в файле main.py происходит импорт модуля file1. Казалось бы, ничего сложного, просто пропишем в main.py:
import utils.file1

а в file1.py пропишем:
import utils.file2

но это работает лишь при запуске main.py, а при запуске file1.py (т.е. скорее всего будет задействована конструкция if __name__ == "__main__") - нет. Я пробовал уже кучу способов, но так ничего и не нашёл. Не хотелось бы также использовать костыль с добавлением директории в path. Есть ли у этой проблемы решение? Или такое просто стоит избегать?

from . import file2

@vitidev при запуске file1.py будет ошибка: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package, так как python нужна директория родителя для относительного импорта

да, есть такое. просто делайте тогда import file2 в if __name__ == "__main__". Хотя лучше такого вообще избегать.

@vitidev теперь всё ясно, спасибо за ответ вам!

Лично я избавился от этих проблем  в принципе, в зародыше, в теории и на практике, потратив 15 минут на написание скрипта, который делает сборку, делает правильно, делает именно так как мне надо. И без этих глюков. Кстати, такой подход снимает проблемы и с компиляцией автономной сборки с помощью pyinstaller. Не все глупости из книжек надо повторять, некоторые вещи умнее и правильнее делать самому. Одна из них - очень простая техника сборки кода программы.

@FoxFox учту ваше предложение) оно и станет решением моей проблемы, ибо делать всё ручками - пустая трата времени

Могу даже скриптом поделиться, но придётся оформлять как ответ, иначе тут будут проблемы с форматированием. Идея проста - собрать все .py в один .py, расположив функции в том порядке, в котором мне нужно. Можно сразу и скомпилировать .pyc. Собрать из нескольких текстовых файлов один - задачка средней сложности для самого неискушенного школьника. Поклонники писанины импортов в пичарме и писатели нелепостей в книжках будут в ярости. Думаю, нет необходимости писать, что такой скрипт кочует дальше из проекта в проект, меняется только список объединяемых в один .py. "Проблемы" исчезают.

@FoxFox я так и не понял чем вам так импорты перешли дорогу, но на вашу реализацию бы взглянул

Что вы запускаете в file1.py? Как вы его запускаете?

Я уже всё объяснил. Никому ничего не навязываю. Жизнь - борьба, а страданиями душа совершенствуется. Боритесь и поборете. Amgarak, в книжках пять страниц "теории" посвящается созданию файла с кодом программы, который в результате и исполняется. Для "программистов", которые самостоятельно не умеют выполнять файловые операции. Я умею, потому объединяю файлы со скриптами САМ. Просто как тексты! И в том порядке, как мне надо!

Вот и всё. Это избавляет от кучи опасной и глючной писанины, пример которой здесь и наблюдается. Вторичный эффект - у меня не бывает проблем со сборкой pyinstaller и просто с работой финального скрипта в автономном режиме (запуск .py или .pyc просто в операционной системе).

@FoxFox забыл добавить что технология копирования кода имеет свои недостатки. Например: копирование кода с ошибками, ошибки из-за использования одного глобального пространства имён, трудности в использовании чужих библиотек, трудности с отладкой (несоответствие исходного кода исполнимому). Сам рецепт прост и понятен, но имеет свою цену, которая растёт непропорционально с ростом сложности проекта.


Копирование кода с ошибками - это о чём? Вылетит ошибку и будет ровно то же, что и при другом способе. 2) Использование глобального пространства - ни о чём, никакой разницы. Вы можете организовывать расположение функций и их вложенность ровно так же, как делали до того. 3) трудности в использовании чужих библиотек - ни о чём, точно такие же "трудности", как и в других вариантах. 4) трудности с отладкой - ни о чём. Открываю собранный код в IDLE и в случае ошибки будет ровно то же показано, что и в других вариантах.



Сложность проекта - это о чём? Например, написан мной комплекс программ по обслуживанию Windows плюс туда же утилиты типа поиска файлов, менеджера драйверов, получения хэш, скачивания с Ютюб, графики использования пространства на диске, информация о системе и ещё куча. "Трудности", которые портят жизнь многим  в части использования функций в Питоне, я оседлал и чудесно использую. Никаких конфликтов имён у меня нет и  быть не может. Использую классы, не ленюсь использовать продуманные имена, не называю имена как функции, имена функций тоже продуманы.


Я всё-таки ещё попробую пояснить. Вся эта писанина с импортами делает ТО ЖЕ САМОЕ, что и я вручную, - собирает код скриптов в один. Все проблемы в обоих случаях ОДИНАКОВЫ. В моём случае писать меньше, риска меньше, нет сюрпризов, нет сюрпризов при запуске в ОС и сборке с помощью pyinstaller конечного продукта, потому что pyinstaller "скармливается" один файл, который уже точно проверен в части автономной работы в ОС.
